# CPU Time of Tasks in Ada

Tags: time, task, cpu, ada

I have a program in which there are about 10 tasks running at the same time. They are all calling the same function with different values, and I want to know how long it takes for each one of my tasks to execute this function. However, it seems to me that I can't use something like that :

```
A:=Clock;
MyFunction(...);
B:=Clock;
Time:= B-A;
```

Indeed, I think this would not return the "real" CPU Time, but the time elapsed between the beginning and the end of the function, which is not correct, because my tasks could be switched when they're executing the function. So, I'm wondering if there is a way to know the "real" CPU time of each one of my tasks, i.e. the time they really spent using the CPU ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need the facilities of [Annex D.14](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-D-14.html):

> "This subclause describes a language-defined package to measure execution time."

> "The execution time or CPU time of a given task is defined as the time spent by the system executing that task, including the time spent executing run-time or system services on its behalf."

This is specified in Ada 2005 and Ada 2012. Whether it's available in your compiler on your operating system is another issue! For example, "Execution_Time is not supported in this configuration" on Mac OS X (GNAT GPL 2013, GCC 4.8).

Answer (score 2):

Burns & Welling "Concurrent and Real-time Programming in Ada" describes this as an execution-time clock. (ch15.5 if you can get hold of a copy) and this was added in Ada-2005.

You would be looking for a package in your installation called "Ada.Execution_Time". Hopefully its package spec can tell you all you need to know.

There would probably also be a child package "Ada.Execution_Time.Timers" which would let you set up events to occur , e.g. when a CPU time budget is exceeded.

On my system, using Gnat installed in /usr/local/bin, the relevant file is:
/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/adainclude/a-exetim.ads
and the function you need is Ada.Execution_Time.Clock.